# How to query datastore from dataflow/beam in python

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow, protocol-buffers, apache-beam

Looks like google has released support for querying the datastore from dataflow/beam in python. I'm trying to get it to run locally but I'm running into some issues:

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io.datastore.v1.datastoreio import ReadFromDatastore
from gcloud import datastore

client = datastore.Client('my-project')
query = client.query(kind='Document')

options = get_options()
p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)

entities = p | 'read' >> ReadFromDatastore(project='my-project', query=query)
entities | 'write' >> beam.io.Write(beam.io.TextFileSink('gs://output.txt'))

p.run()
```

This is giving me a

```
AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'HasField' [while running 'read/Split Query']
```

I'm guessing that I'm passing in the wrong query object (there are 3-4 pip packages that you can import datastore from) but I can't figure out which one I'm supposed to pass in. In the tests they are passing in [protobuf](https://github.com/apache/incubator-beam/blob/python-sdk/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/datastore/v1/helper_test.py#L23). Is that what I have to use? Can anyone show a simple example query using protobuf if that's what I have to do?

Comment: Hi Bouvard, where are you running this code? on the app engine? console? or connect thru command line on your desktop? I am having trouble getting started on a similar issue

Comment: Command line on desktop.

Comment: Please have a look at the answer posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44117621/apache-beam-google-datastore-readfromdatastore-entity-protobuf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [wordcount example](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/cookbook/datastore_wordcount.py) uses protobufs for the query.

Looks like you need something like:

```
from google.datastore.v1 import query_pb2
...
query = query_pb2.Query()
query.kind.add().name = 'Document'
```