# Apache Beam Google Datastore ReadFromDatastore entity protobuf

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, protocol-buffers, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to use apache beam's google datastore api to ReadFromDatastore

```
p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)
(p
 | 'Read from Datastore' >> ReadFromDatastore(gcloud_options.project, query)
 | 'reformat'            >> beam.Map(reformat)
 | 'Write To Datastore'  >> WriteToDatastore(gcloud_options.project))
```

The object that gets passed to my reformat function is type

google.cloud.proto.datastore.v1.entity_pb2.Entity

It is in protobuf format which is hard to modify or read.

I think I can convert a entity_pb2.Entity to a dict with

```
entity= dict(google.cloud.datastore.helpers._property_tuples(entity_pb))
```

But for some reason trying to import the following two libraries gives me some errors:

```
import google.cloud.datastore.helpers  
from apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1.datastoreio import ReadFromDatastore
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nburn42/MotoGarage/MotoGarage/MotoGarageBackgroundJobs/format_data.py", line 16, in <module>
    import google.cloud.datastore.helpers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/datastore/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from google.cloud.datastore.batch import Batch
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/datastore/batch.py", line 24, in <module>
    from google.cloud.datastore import helpers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/datastore/helpers.py", line 29, in <module>
    from google.cloud.grpc.datastore.v1 import entity_pb2 as _entity_pb2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/grpc/datastore/v1/entity_pb2.py", line 28, in <module>
    dependencies=[google_dot_api_dot_annotations__pb2.DESCRIPTOR,google_dot_protobuf_dot_struct__pb2.DESCRIPTOR,google_dot_protobuf_dot_timestamp__pb2.DESCRIPTOR,google_dot_type_dot_latlng__pb2.DESCRIPTOR,])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor.py", line 824, in __new__
    return _message.default_pool.AddSerializedFile(serialized_pb)
TypeError: Couldn't build proto file into descriptor pool!
Invalid proto descriptor for file "google/cloud/grpc/datastore/v1/entity.proto":
  google.datastore.v1.PartitionId.project_id: "google.datastore.v1.PartitionId.project_id" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.PartitionId.namespace_id: "google.datastore.v1.PartitionId.namespace_id" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.PartitionId: "google.datastore.v1.PartitionId" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Key.partition_id: "google.datastore.v1.Key.partition_id" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Key.path: "google.datastore.v1.Key.path" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Key.PathElement.id_type: "google.datastore.v1.Key.PathElement.id_type" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Key.PathElement.kind: "google.datastore.v1.Key.PathElement.kind" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Key.PathElement.id: "google.datastore.v1.Key.PathElement.id" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Key.PathElement.name: "google.datastore.v1.Key.PathElement.name" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Key.PathElement: "google.datastore.v1.Key.PathElement" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Key: "google.datastore.v1.Key" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.ArrayValue.values: "google.datastore.v1.ArrayValue.values" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.ArrayValue: "google.datastore.v1.ArrayValue" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Value.value_type: "google.datastore.v1.Value.value_type" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Value.null_value: "google.datastore.v1.Value.null_value" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Value.boolean_value: "google.datastore.v1.Value.boolean_value" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Value.integer_value: "google.datastore.v1.Value.integer_value" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Value.double_value: "google.datastore.v1.Value.double_value" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Value.timestamp_value: "google.datastore.v1.Value.timestamp_value" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Value.key_value: "google.datastore.v1.Value.key_value" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Value.string_value: "google.datastore.v1.Value.string_value" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Value.blob_value: "google.datastore.v1.Value.blob_value" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Value.geo_point_value: "google.datastore.v1.Value.geo_point_value" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Value.entity_value: "google.datastore.v1.Value.entity_value" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Value.array_value: "google.datastore.v1.Value.array_value" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Value.meaning: "google.datastore.v1.Value.meaning" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Value.exclude_from_indexes: "google.datastore.v1.Value.exclude_from_indexes" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Value: "google.datastore.v1.Value" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Entity.key: "google.datastore.v1.Entity.key" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Entity.properties: "google.datastore.v1.Entity.properties" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Entity.PropertiesEntry.key: "google.datastore.v1.Entity.PropertiesEntry.key" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Entity.PropertiesEntry.value: "google.datastore.v1.Entity.PropertiesEntry.value" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Entity.PropertiesEntry: "google.datastore.v1.Entity.PropertiesEntry" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Entity: "google.datastore.v1.Entity" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Key.partition_id: "google.datastore.v1.PartitionId" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/grpc/datastore/v1/entity.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
  google.datastore.v1.Key.path: "google.datastore.v1.Key.PathElement" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/grpc/datastore/v1/entity.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
  google.datastore.v1.ArrayValue.values: "google.datastore.v1.Value" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/grpc/datastore/v1/entity.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
  google.datastore.v1.Value.key_value: "google.datastore.v1.Key" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/grpc/datastore/v1/entity.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
  google.datastore.v1.Value.entity_value: "google.datastore.v1.Entity" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/grpc/datastore/v1/entity.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
  google.datastore.v1.Value.array_value: "google.datastore.v1.ArrayValue" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/grpc/datastore/v1/entity.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
  google.datastore.v1.Entity.PropertiesEntry.value: "google.datastore.v1.Value" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/grpc/datastore/v1/entity.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
  google.datastore.v1.Entity.key: "google.datastore.v1.Key" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/grpc/datastore/v1/entity.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
  google.datastore.v1.Entity.properties: "google.datastore.v1.Entity.PropertiesEntry" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/grpc/datastore/v1/entity.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
```

Is there something I can do to convert a entity_pb2.Entity to something usable?
Is the ReadFromDatastore just too new for real use right now?
Is there another approach I should be using?

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: Try taking a look at the `com.google.datastore.v1` package and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of Apache Beam 2.13 deprecates this old approach of using the old `googledatastore` library, and adds a new implementation that uses the newer and more human-friendly `google-cloud-datastore` library.

https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.13.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1new.datastoreio.html

https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/8262

There's still an open issue to add an example, so for now you'll have to figure that part out.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-7350

Answer (score 5):

I was getting the same issue and the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49450944/498463) didn't work for me.

The OP has 3 questions:

**1. Is there something I can do to convert a entity_pb2.Entity to something usable?**

You don't specify exactly what difficulty you are having in using the returned value but all instances of entity_pb2.Entity should have a `properties` property. You should then be able to use that to get the values out of your entity. e.g. `property_value = entity.properties.get('<your_property_name>')`

---

**Update:** I think I now might know what the OP meant by "usable", as even when you do `property_value = entity.properties.get('<your_property_name>')` the value you get in `property_value` is in the protocol buffer format... So to get a dict of properties you can do this...

```
from googledatastore import helper

value_dict = dict((prop_name, helper.get_value(entity.properties.get(prop_name)),) for prop_name in entity.properties)
```

---

**2. Is the ReadFromDatastore just too new for real use right now?**

I too initially thought the same but I seem to have it working now (see my answer to Q3 below).

**3. Is there another approach I should be using?**

You absolutely must not import the `google-cloud-datastore` library into your project. Doing so will cause the `TypeError: Couldn't build proto file into descriptor pool!` error that was in your original question to be raised when you import `ReadFromDatastore` from `apache_beam`.

From the investigation/debugging I've been doing it seems that the current version of the `apache-beam (v2.8.0)` library is simply incompatible with the `google-cloud-datastore (v1.7.1)` library. This means we must instead use the [bundled](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/setup.py) `googledatastore (v7.0.1)` library instead to achieve what we want.

**Further reading / reference(s):**

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/how-to-do-data-processing-and-analytics-from-google-app-engine-with-google-cloud-dataflow

https://github.com/amygdala/gae-dataflow

https://gcloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/0.10.0/_modules/gcloud/datastore/helpers.html

Comment: It seems that google-cloud-datastore and googledatastore can coexist to a limited degree, if one adds ['pip uninstall -y protobuf', 'pip install protobuf==3.7.1 --no-binary=protobuf'] to the custom_commands section in setup.py .

Comment: As an extra FYI, the id can be accessed at `element.key.path[-1].id`

Answer (score 4):

An alternative (and easier) way to specify the query is the following:

```
from google.cloud import datastore
from google.cloud.datastore import query as datastore_query
from apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1.datastoreio import ReadFromDatastore

p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
ds_client = datastore.Client(project=project)
query = ds_client.query(kind=kind)
# possible filter: query.add_filter('column','operator',criteria) 
# query.add_filter('age','>',18)
# query.add_filter('name','=',"John")
query = datastore_query._pb_from_query(query)

p | 'ReadFromDatastore' >> ReadFromDatastore(project=project, query=query)
p.run().wait_until_finish()
```

When transmitting the job to the DataflowRunner (in the cloud), make sure your local requirements are in line with the setup.py file you are transmitting to google cloud. I have experienced that you must install apache beam 2.1.0 on your local machine and then specifying the same version in your setup.py file in order for it to work on the cloud workers.

Comment: In particular, for me it was that my setup.py google-cloud-datastore was unversioned, but my local installation had an older, pinned version. This caused a conflict when running on the cloud. Pinning both versions fixed it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function `google.cloud.datastore.helpers.entity_from_protobuf` to convert `entity_pb2.Entity` to `google.cloud.datastore.entity.Entity`.

`google.cloud.datastore.entity.Entity` is a subclass of dict and will give you the usability you need.

Comment: This solution works great with Apache Beam running on a local machine. However, when pushing the job to DataflowRunner, the job fails saying it can't find `datastore` in `google.cloud`. Is this because Datastore support for Apache Beam Python SDK is still in beta?

Comment: When you deploy a pipeline to Google Dataflow workers using Apache Beam, your Python environment doesn't get replicated on worker machines. The problem is that worker machines don't have google-cloud-datastore package installed by default while your local environment does. For instructions on specifying PyPI dependencies, see: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/dependencies-python